# Why won't blender files open?

Tags: blend-files

I have a student that has been working on a project recently and finally got the steps to work. However, when she tries to open the files in blender, it won't open. Instead, it takes her to the page as if she was saving it again. Any ideas on why this is happening? I have never ran into this problem before.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably saved the file while you had file browser window open instead of 3D view window, try to switch it back when you open the file.

Comment: Keystroke Shift F5 for the 3D View.  Sometimes the escape key will work.  Or use the little button on the bottom left typically.  All windows can be switched to another type.

Comment: Also when selecting the file to open you can turn off the 'Load UI' option.

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck the "Load UI" button when loading the file. That'll keep the user interface as it was before, instead of loading it from the blend file.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, but I easily fixed it. It happened to me since i saved the file while in the Save As page, and knowing this, i clicked on "Back to Previous". This doesn't exit blender, but returns back to the same state as when you saved. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I have been having a similar problem and I have finally figured out a solution. If you are using Windows, go to the .BLEND file you want to open and put it up in a smaller window. Left hold on the file and drag over to the Blender icon program on your desktop and click "Open in Blender." It should open just fine.

Comment: This is the same as just simple open of the file which won't allow changing Blender UI setup on loading a file. It will be opened fine only if everything is already fine with the file itself as well.